# How do you trim strings in Fish Shell

Tags: fish

Say you have:

```
set x "   abcd "
```

How can you trim it to `"abcd"`?  Is there a standard function to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In future fish versions, there's a `string` command that has a `trim` function, so `set x (string trim -- "     abcd ")` will work.

In absence of that, you'll have to use general unix tools like `sed`, with something like `set x (echo "     abcd " | sed 's/^\s\+\(.\+\)\s\+$/\1/'')`.

Comment: I can't find any good books, is there a fish book ala, the bash book from decades ago?  Thanks!

Comment: No. For these general utilities, general documentation applies. For everything fish brings to the table, there's http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html (also installed on your system and accessible in a browser via `help` from fish).

Comment: Can't really get `string trim` to work as part of `fzf` so sed it is.

Comment: `string` is a fish builtin. It only exists inside of a running fish. So if you're telling fzf to run it, you'll have to run it as `fish -c 'string trim ...'`.